# What's the equivalent of JavaScript Array.from in C# (without while/for)?

Tags: c#

I'm getting used to JS after a few years of Node.js programming and I'm wondering how we could avoid **while** loops in C# to add items in an array by using a more "map-like" method (like AddRange in C# enumerables).

For example, if I want an array of 10 elements in JavaScript, each having a property that is incremented each time, I would do:

```
const cells = Array.from({ length:10 }, (_, i) => { 'number': i });
// gives cells = [{number: 0}, {number: 1}, ... until 9]
```

How to do that in C# without a `while` or `for` loop ?

```
int itemWantedCount = 10;
int i = 0;
while(cells.Count < itemWantedCount)
{
   cells.Add(new MyObject(i++));
}
```

I'd like to find a method to use cells.AddRange instead, without for/while usage, if that's possible.

Comment: IEnumerable<int> items = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => x * x);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) for functional-style list processing in C#. Example:

```
// We don't need Select in this toy example, but this is where
// you would put your "map" operation.
var cells = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => i).ToArray();
            
// prints 0123456789
foreach (var c in cells)
    Console.Write(c);
```

Explanation:

- `Enumerable.Range(start, count)` enumerates our numbers (lazily - nothing happens until the call to `ToArray()` later).
- `Select` is "map" - you are already familiar with that. In your example, you'd replace `i => i`  with `i => new MyObject(i)`.
- `ToArray()`: Materializes the lazily created enumeration. Since arrays are fixed-size in C#, a more idiomatic alternative would be `ToList()`.